# Native Ads vs Interstitial ads vs banner ads which one will generate more revenue? how to implement native ads?

Tags: android, admob, adsense, ads, native-ads

I couldn't find any useful link to the newly added native ads. can anyone give me the link to the documentation.

Can i use the Native ads and banner ads in one screen. Is this a violation of admob policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like Native Ads Express from AdMob might be a good fit for you. Here's some links that can show you how it's done:

- [iOS implementation guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/native-express)
- [Android implementation guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express)
- [Objective-C example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Objective-C/admob/NativeExpressExample)
- [Swift example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/admob)
- [Android example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeExpressExample)

You're welcome to use both banners and Native Express ads in the same Activity or ViewController, but it's important that only one ad be visible onscreen at a time. That's one of the publisher policies for AdMob.

Comment: Does Admob usually pay more for native ads than banner ads, though?

Answer (score 4):

I'd also add that native ads work better in apps, not in games, because you can place and design them the way you like, as a banner or an ad in the app's feed and so on.
I personally think that rewarded videos and interstitials are best for games, at the same time 320x50 banners are really disturbing, often they make users angry.

Anyway, from the financial point of view, native ads and interstitials bring a way more revenue comparing to banners. And video/rew video often bring even more.

Haven't tried Facebook's and Amazon's native ads directly, cause i mediate ads (interst + vids) through Appodeal, covering both networks. Definitely recommend.

adding link to their native ads implementation guide, if u r interested http://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=1&full=1#p_4_6  (it's for android native, you can choose options at the top of the page)

Comment: Good suggestions, but the link is not working anymore...

Answer (score 3):

A native ad is a non intrusive way to promote products and services.

It fits any platform, any theme and any content to keep the focus on the main content of the app / web page.

Using to many publicities is too much intrusive. It is not a violation, but users wont like it.

I guess your goal is to publish an app, not a pub banner. But I guess you want to make money with it !

Think about Facebook and Amazon which paid per View instead of Admob which paid per click. They both have accurate pub API to make more money.

Facebook 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/native-api

Amazon
https://advertising.amazon.com/apps-self-serve?ref_=A20M_footer

Comment: I haven't tried the facebook and Amazon pay per view service. Can you share a link to their documetation if possible?. Thanks

Comment: I think that admob also let you earn by view,  i dont know how big is the earning witj Amazon and facebook but admob ads small amount even I dont have clicks sometimes